# Storing Extracted Variables into Dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary and I am not sure how to store the extracted variables back into my dictionary so that I can return the dictionary.

```
data = """Amanda:100
Katie:90
Eric:78
Mike:45
Paul:71"""
```

This was given data.

```
# write a function parseData() which:
#      parses the initial data (data),
#      stores them in a dictionary, and
#      returns the dictionary to the caller.
#      The student name must be the key of the dictionary, and
#      the student grade  its corresponding value
```

I created the function and added the empty dictionary.

```
def parseData():

# Initialize an empty dictionary.
    students = dict()

#  After initializing the dictionary, scan all the lines of the data string provided.
    infos = data.split('\n')
    print infos

#  For each line that you get, extract the student and the student scores from that line and
#  store it in a two variables: name and scores
    for info in infos:
        names = info.split(':')
        print names
        name = names[0]
        score = names[1]
        print score
        students[name] = score
```

This is where I am stuck. To store the variables, I was thinking of putting this:

```
#   Store the extracted variables name and scores in the dictionary initialized in and
#   return that dictionary
    students[info] = score()[info]
    return students
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dict` constructor like this

```
print dict(line.split(":") for line in data.splitlines())
# {'Paul': '71', 'Mike': '45', 'Amanda': '100', 'Eric': '78', 'Katie': '90'}
```

This can be written as

```
result = {}
for line in data.splitlines():
    splitted_values = line.split(":")
    result[splitted_values[0]] = splitted_values[1]
print result
```

Comment: This looks like a shorthand answer, how would it look step by step?

Comment: @Cassandra Please check my answer. But the first version is the most efficient way.